# Git Bash: Not accepting my keyboard input

Tags: windows, git-bash

So, I have reproduced it. Running:
`git ls-files|grep navbar.html|xargs vim`

 in my `Git Bash` and exiting vim making my `Git Bash` not accept keyboard inputs anymore. However my other `Git Bash` windows working fine.
Any ideas how can I get arround this problem?

Comment: It does accept input, but doesn't show them. Try typing something and pressing enter, it will show the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you execute reset, it will be fixed.

Comment: Hi @MSathieu, typing 'reset' did display nothing but it actually make the issue go away! Cheers :)

Comment: You could still type but it just didn't show your input. Strange issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common vim usage error (see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77395/grep-l-xargs-vim-generates-a-warning-why). This command will do what you want:

`git ls-files | grep navbar.html | xargs sh -c 'vim "$@" <$0' /dev/tty`

Comment: Hi Johannes, My vim is now giving:$ git ls-files|grep navbar.html|xargs vim -
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Jun  1 2017 21:25:47)
Too many edit arguments: "src/main/resources/templates/fragments/navbar.html"
More info with: "vim -h"

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes like when you are not on full screen and you insert command like

> git log   |   git diff

or something like them that need a bigger window size to show bunch of data you'll get **colon sign**

> ```
>    :
> ```

that is for displaying data summary and you can scroll data to see more by using arrow keys.
at the end you can quit this mode using **q** key

> press **"Q"** keyword to exit.